# I want to create a Shorcut which execute a code when clicked

Tags: executable

I want to create a file, which will execute a code in terminal when dbl clicked.. Can this be done? If Yes, How?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need to create a file ending with a .sh file extension.
put
    #!/bin/bash
on the first line by itself.

Then enter your terminal code.

You will need to right-click on the file, choose properties, go to the permissions tab, and check the box to allow executing the file.

You may need to open nautilus and go to edit > preferences > behavior and choose run executable text files when they are opened, or ask each time.

You can right-click on the file to make a link, and choose make link. Double-clicking on the file that is generated will execute the code.

Comment: That is creating a script, not a launcher.

Comment: Added info at the bottom.

Comment: A symlink is also not a launcher. However, this question has already been marked a duplicate.

Comment: He never asked about a launcher. He wanted to create a file that would execute code.